# They have a big project to launch a new product

Tags: to-infinitive, adjuncts

> They have a big project to launch a new product.

Does this sentence sound natural?

If so, in the natural reading, what's the syntactic function of "to launch a new product"?

---

This is not about sentence correction. This is specifically about the syntactic function of "to launch a new product".

Someone has argued that "to launch a new product" here is functioning as a purpose adjunct describing the purpose of "have a big project". I disagreed, so I'm asking it here. For me, the only possible function of "to launch a new product" is to modify "project" thereby forming a noun phrase "a big project to launch a new product".

Comment: @Lambie It's not sentence correction that I'm asking for. I've edited the question.

Comment: Asking if something sounds natural can only be answered by making changes to your suggestion or not; In my book, that is sentence correction.

Comment: @Lambie I've made clear that I'm not seeking any sentence correction. I'm not really asking for another way of putting it. All I'm asking is, in its natural interpretation, what's the function of "to launch a new product". I don't understand why you're arguing it's sentence correction when it's not, even after I've explained why I have posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

> They have a big project to launch a new product.

I would more likely use **a large ceremony** or **a/an marketing/advertising bliz/campaign**, which are more precise than *a big project* is.

Edit

The nonfinite clause *to launch a new product* can be adjectival or adverbial.

Try moving it to the front:

> To launch a new product, they have a big project.

This works, and hence adverbial use is possible.

Your reasoning for an adjectival use is also possible.  Hence, we will rely on context.

If the background of discussion is about the nature of this *big project*,

> What kind of project is that?

the adjectival use is likely.

If the discussion is about the reasons for the *big project*,

> Why do they have that project?

the adverbial use is likely.

Comment: Thanks. Alternatively, can the nonfinite clause _to launch a new product_ modify the verb phrase _have a big project_? In other words, can the nonfinite clause denote the purpose of "have a big project"?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Some cultures give importance to the contribution of people [more than/ as much as/ less than] the importance of things. Consequently, more, equal or less value is given to the Team over the product, depending on the milieu. This can come across in the sentence structure.

Then again, it may be just how they learned the language.

The function of "to launch a new product" is to highlight the importance of the project team. The creation of the project team for the new product launch means that the launch is important to the company. The Project Team is responsible for ensuring that the new product is successful on behalf of the company.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. FYI, I've edited the question to make it clearer. It'd be nice if you could edit your answer accordingly.